# Django 1.6 uWSGI + nginx wont serve static files

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have a Django 1.6 application for testing purpose as shown:

```
media folder -> /home/josealejandro93/Desktop/Soporte/media
static folder -> /home/josealejandro93/Desktop/Soporte/static
root folder -> /home/josealejandro93/Desktop/Soporte  # manage.py lives here!
```

I managed to configure uwsgi using [this tutorial](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) on Linux Arch and when I run

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --module soporte.wsgi
```

I can see my application running on `localhost:8000` however by following the configuration instructions in the tutorial pointed above I wasn't able to serve static files so I tried a new configuration for my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  1;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;      
            root   /home/josealejandro93/Desktop/Soporte;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }


        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }


}
```

As you can see, that file is just a basic configuration file but I'm still not able to serve my static files.

Any idea on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which port are you trying to use? You have Nginx on port 80 and the WSGI application on port 8000.

Comment: I want to use port 80, but accessing `localhost/media/nocap.jpg` yields Nginx 404. nocap.jpg is a file that exists under `/home/josealejandro93/Desktop/Soporte/media`

Comment: Check the permissions. Serving content from your home directory with a non priv nginx user will probably cause issues.

Comment: Tried using user = josealejandro93; with no luck

Comment: The answer is in the nginx error log.

Comment: Checked /var/log/nginx/ and the only file there is access.log which has strings like: `127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:21:34:15 -0500] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36"
`

Answer (score 0):

You should configure nginx to recognize and serve media and static files:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;      
        root   /home/josealejandro93/Desktop/Soporte;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /static/ { 
        alias /home/josealejandro93/Desktop/Soporte/static;
    }

    location /media/ { 
        alias /home/josealejandro93/Desktop/Soporte/media;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you reload nginx afterward?

Comment: yes, first `sudo nginx -t` and then `sudo systemctl restart nginx` . Also with start-stop.

Comment: Have you configured your media and static URLs in settings.py?